# Create Horizontal lines in jointjs

Tags: jointjs

How to create horizontal line in jointjs.I want to draw simple horizontal lines between two points in joint js .Can someone please tell me how to do that.

My papers look like :

```
  var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#myholder'),
        width: w,
        height:h,
        model: graph,
        gridsize:4
    });
    var paper2 = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#myimage'),
        width: w,
        height:600,
        model: graph,
        interactive : false
    });
```

And I have created two horizontal line like:

```
  var line = V('line', { x1: 50, y1: 100, x2: 300, y2: 100, stroke: 'black' });
    V(paper.viewport).append(line);
    V(paper2.viewport).append(line);
```

But I am not getting the line in paper while line is printed in paper2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a link for that:

```
graph.addCell(new joint.dia.Link({
   source: { x: 50, y: 100 },
   target: { x: 300, y: 100 }
}))
```

Or SVG:

```
var line = V('line', { x1: 50, y1: 100, x2: 300, y2: 100, stroke: 'black' });
V(paper.viewport).append(line);
```

`V` is a global variable exported by JointJS and is a tiny library for easier SVG manipulation that is called Vectorizer (http://jointjs.com/api#v).

Keep in mind that if you want to add another line into the other paper (`paper2`), you must first clone the first one:

```
V(paper2.viewport).append(line.clone())
```

If you don't do that, the line from `paper` is taken out and appended to the `paper2`, that's why you don't see the line in `paper` anymore.

Comment: I tried the V library for adding vertical line but it is not shown when I used interactive=false options in the paper

Comment: Could you be more specific? There is no connection between the `interactive: false` option on the paper and the Vectorizer library.

Comment: Hey I have edit the problem statement .have a look at it

Comment: I followed the advise to work on the viewport with `V` (seems to be more logical than adding a link), but note that when you call `resetCells`, the whole viewport is cleared, so better listen of `reset` signals from the `graph` and re-draw it then.